# sampleRegions deleting input feature collection properties, how to stop that?

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do I retain the existing properties of an input feature collection to sampleregions, as well as the ones that it extracts from the images? When I leave it to default it deletes the input properties and only has the image extracted values.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the argument `properties` to do that. See the explanation GEE provides in the documentation on `sampleRegion()`:

> **properties (List, default: null):** The list of properties to copy from
> each input feature. Defaults to all non-system properties.

An example would be:

```
// define sample image and feature collection
var sampleFeatCol = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(point1, {prop1: 1, prop2: 2, 'system:time_start': 10000}),
  ee.Feature(point2, {prop1: 2, prop2: 1, 'system:time_start': 10000})]);
var image = ee.Image(1);

// define the properties to retain
var listProperties = ['prop1','system:time_start'];

sampleFeatCol = image.sampleRegions(sampleFeatCol, listProperties, 100)

print(sampleFeatCol)
```

[link example code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fec0891f1d8703712f7fcbc10d5611a1)

Answer (score 0):

As Kuik said, the param "properties" in sampleRegions( ) is corresponded to param "collection" in sampleRegions?
"listProperties" must corresponds to sampleFeatCol.propertyNames()?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/236874)

Comment: get it, sorry my bro